# VSTS - Android signing - The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to sign my apk before deploying it.
Here the yaml snippet:

```
- task: AndroidSigning@2
    displayName: 'Signing'
    inputs:
        apkFiles: 'Platforms/MyApp.Android/bin/Release/*.apk'
        jarsign: true
        jarsignerKeystoreFile: 'mykey.keystore'
        jarsignerKeystorePassword: '$(myKeyPassword)'
        jarsignerKeystoreAlias: "mykey"
        jarsignerKeyPassword: '$(myKeyPassword)'
        zipalign: true
```

The issue is that while the file `mykey.keystore` is there at the root of solution (checked into source control) I got the following yaml validation error:

> Phase Android: Step input jarsignerKeystoreFile references secure file
>   mykey.keystore which could not be found. The secure file does
>   not exist or has not been authorized for use.

Comment: I see you made the same mistake I did and read the docs ... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to what the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/android-signing?view=vsts) says, the keystore file cannot be from source control. It has to be a `secure file` uploaded in the `library` of the build definitions (see this [post](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplified-app-signing-secure-files-visual-studio-team-services/)).

So upload that file then start the creation of a manual build definition, pick the `Android Signing` task, there is a dropdown for the secure file. Select the file you uploaded in the library and then click on "View YAML". Then you can see the correct input to use `jarsignerKeystoreFile: '<someId>'`.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Comment: I can't the the GUI to work and I am trying to build a .yml file, is there any way to find this Id without going through the UI. @MarinaLiu-MSFT ?

Comment: The assembleRelease task failed because it was missing the key file.
"How is it supposed to work?"

Answer (score 2):

This is a build configuration that works for me:

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  - group: 'Android Signing keys'

steps:
  - task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      tasks: 'assembleRelease'

  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    inputs:
      secureFile: key-store.jks

  - task: AndroidSigning@3
    inputs:
      apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
      apksign: true
      apksignerKeystoreFile: 'key-store.jks'
      apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD)'
      apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(KEYSTORE_ALIAS)'
      apksignerKeyPassword: '$(KEY_PASSWORD)'
      # When it was set to true the task threw this error:
      # zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
      zipalign: false

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: '**/*.apk'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Comment: did you ever figure out how to get the zipalign working?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Crazy, I've just popped this into my script and it's now queued. If I follow the MS docs on how to make this work, it all implodes. What hope have we got if the docs are so misleading?